# How else can you say "use aggressive language?"

Tags: synonyms

How else can you say *use **aggressive** language*?

What other word or phrase can I use to describe *aggressive* in a neutral way like forceful or strong, not hostile and not assertive either?

Comment: Why not use "forceful" instead?

Comment: Word or phrase requests of this sort require an example sentence to illustrate the intended use.

Comment: Please explain why 'assertive' isn't the neutral word you are looking for.

Comment: Used too many times already so DS is looking for an alternative. Sorry, I'd put more context, but that is all I got as well. He might end up using "forceful" if there is no other good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Here's bold and powerful language asking DS to do its own question. Is DS someone we know?

Comment: "Used too many times already" is literally why we have [thesauruses](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/aggressive). Loads of words there, with the "assertive" meaning especially relevant.

Comment: Please edit additional information into the question. Comments may be deleted, and many potential answerers will not read all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say ***authoritative***:

> showing that you are confident, in control, and expect to be respected and obeyed:
>
> - She has an *authoritative* manner that at times is almost arrogant. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/authoritative))

***[Compelling](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compelling)*** could also be an option, it has the right meaning, but it is too commonly used as a synonym of *convincing*, so it might not be the best choice.